# How to add a field in python to return value based on other columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a new field in python based on the values of other fields. For Example, column Pop2020 has values ranging from 0-10000. If the value is between 0-200 then I want a new field to indicate "0-200", if the values are between 201-500, then return "201-500" and so on and so forth. I thought of using a statement below but that only returns true or false values. I thought maybe I should use the append function but not sure what would work to get what I need.

```
excl['TestFlag'] = np.where(excl['Pop2020'] > 0 and < 201, True, False)
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html. will help enomously

Comment: Yes, Just use `pd.cut(excl['TestFlag'], bins=[0,200, 500, ...], right=True)`, for `right` default True
Indicates whether bins includes the rightmost edge or not. If right == True (the default), then the bins [1, 2, 3, 4] indicate (1,2], (2,3], (3,4]. This argument is ignored when bins is an IntervalIndex.

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following example may help you. You can use [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) which receives a callable and apply it element-wise to a column:

```
import pandas as pd
def f(x):
    if 10 < x:
        return 'a'
    elif 5 < x <= 10:
        return 'b'
    else:
        return 'c'

df = pd.DataFrame({"num1":[1,10,11,2,6,4,8], "num2":[0,1,0,1,2,0,7]})
df["new_col"] = df["num1"].apply(f)

#   num1  num2 new_col
#0     1     0       c
#1    10     1       b
#2    11     0       a
#3     2     1       c
#4     6     2       b
#5     4     0       c
#6     8     7       b
```